# "object reference not set to an instance of an object" getting error when calling .net webservice in ajax javascript

Tags: ajax

Please some one help me.

my problem is that when i call the .net webservice using ajax windows phone 8(phonegap app), i get  error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in POST method json formate send in data.

on server side json was receved all values as null.

my ajax is

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                            dataType: "json",
                            processData: true,
                            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                                console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()+"ajax.responseText==>" + jqXHR.responseText);

                            },
                            error: function (xhr) {

                                console.log(xhr.responseText+"<==ajax.getAllResponseHeaders==>"+xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());


                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

do not stringify data before sending